# SQL server CTE recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Could anyone please explain to me how is the following query working ?

```sql
with my_query (my_date) as (select convert(date, '03-10-2021', 105)
                            union all
                            select dateadd(day, 1, my_date)
                            from my_query
                            where my_date <= convert(date, '03-10-2021', 105))

select *
from my_query;
```

What I think about is that this query will enter an infinite loop because each time it executes the recursive part of the query it still finds rows in data, But actually the query terminates and returns result ad this is strange.

Appreciate any explaination for my question.

Thanks

Comment: An rCTE only iterates for as long as the bottom query returns rows. For the above, that'll result in 2 rows; the row from the upper `SELECT`, and then 1 from the bottom select, as for the second iteration the value of  `my_date` will be `2021-10-04`, which is *not* `<= '2021-10-03'`

Comment: I thought that when entering the recursive part it will check the whole result of my_query result set which always contains 03-10-2021 so it will enter an infinite loop but this appears to be incorrect assumption from me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

your query always retrun two rows :

first select :

```
 select  convert(date, '03-10-2021', 105)
```

returns  : '03-10-2021'

the recursive part you are checking my_date which is right now '03-10-2021' to be equal or greater than '03-10-2021', which is true and it returns `dateadd(day, 1, my_date)`:

2021-10-04

so next level of recursion , now my_day = '2021-10-04' and the condition check if  '2021-10-04' <= convert(date, '03-10-2021', 105) which is false , so recursion stops

Comment: I thought that when entering the recursive part it will check the whole result of my_query result set which always contains 03-10-2021 so it will enter an infinite loop but this appears to be incorrect assumption from me. Thanks so much.

Comment: @IhabTaher you are welcome , please upvote /accept if it helped.